# How to name a Boolean variable that represents either of two options?

Tags: naming, coding-standards, variables, naming-standards, boolean

I'm developing an application with Python. I want to have a Boolean variable that represent whether something is `buy` or `sell` but I'm not sure how I should name it. Here are my current ideas:

- isBuy
- isSell
- buy_sell
- sell_buy
- buy1_sell0

actually I like the last one the most although it's somehow the ugliest because it tells you all you need to know about it with certainty. However I thought I'd ask some more experienced people to see what is the actual python convention for such situations.

Comment: Or maybe the name is less important if you use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead of a boolean?

Comment: An enum is likely best. IsBuy or isSell is just about acceptable. Buy_sell and the others are just awful. You might as well have “isBuyOrSell” which always returns true.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't use a Boolean. Use an enum. E.g `TransactionType` with instances `Buy` and `Sell`.

That is unambiguous and far easier to understand.

If you want to persist the data efficiently, the boolean can be a good solution as long as there are only two instances in the enum. However, your code need not be efficient at that level of detail (that's the interpreters job); it needs to be very understandable. The enum achieves that goal far better.

Comment: Additionally, an enum gives you the option to easily extend the data type in case a new option needs to be added, e.g. "Lend".

Comment: Another bonus is that you can add logic to the enum. Example sign(), taxCode(), etc.

Comment: @Borjab: depends on the language. It's possible in Python and Java, but in most other languages, enums cannot have functionality.

Comment: Also possible to add logic to enums in PHP, where enums are really special types of classes & objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **is** or **has** keyword in prefix to show that it is a Boolean variable.
So, according to me first and second variable names are preferable instead of other variables as it clearly shows the meaning of the variable. Some of the built-in boolean variable name are as follows:

```
isalnum()
isalpha()
isdecimal()
isdigit()
isidentifier()
islower()
isnumeric()
isprintable()
isspace()
istitle()
isupper()
```